# Binance Smart Chain Payments

Tags: cryptography, token, binance

I've been searching around the web to see what is available for payment processing on the BSC network. There doesn't seem to be much, unless I am just slow and missing the details.
What I am looking for is the ability to accept payment of a BSC TOKEN and track it.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. bscscan.com allows to track the transactions by wallet addresses. However I don't know how to use it to check a specific payment. Some API's are available for bitcoin and other coins to check payments. Maybe same kind of mechanism should be created manually for a bsc token.

Comment: Very odd right ... noone is trying to payment

Comment: I have created my own payment system for a bsc token. I create a temporary wallet and let the customer transfer the token to this wallet, then I send the token to my wallet from temporary token. After process has been complated I remove the temporary token. Each temporary token is for one process.